# Notation for Ring Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation

If $K$ is a field extension of a field $F$ (that is, $F\subseteq K$), we write $K/F$. But if $R$ is a *ring* extension of the ring $S$ (that is, $S\subseteq R$), what is the equivalent notation? Do we write $R/S$ like we would for fields or is something like $R\supseteq S$ more appropriate?

Comment: See also [Why is $S/R$ a ring extension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/311617/242)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any generally accepted definition of a "ring extension" with no further qualifiers. When you go beyond the case of fields it's much less clear that "an injection $S \to R$" is the correct notion of "ring extension." On the one hand you may want to discuss an arbitrary map $f : S \to R$, not necessarily injective; equivalently, you may want $R$ to be an arbitrary $S$-algebra. This is the most general thing you could ask for and has nice categorical properties. On the other hand you may want to require various properties of the map $f$: for example, that it's

- [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element) (which generalizes algebraic extensions)
- [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_morphism) (automatic if $S$ is a field)
- [faithfully flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module#Faithfully_flat_ring_homomorphism) (various nice properties)
- [etale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_morphism) (also very nice properties but very restrictive)

and lots and lots of other possibilities. I am also not aware of notation for any of these. People just say "let $f : S \to R$ be (whatever)." (Also, it would be standard to write $f : R \to S$ here.)

Comment: I didn't think a ring extension was a mapping. If I understood correctly, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ was a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, while $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ was a ring extension of $\mathbb{Z}$. Am I getting the terminology mixed up here?

Comment: @Math: I am just not aware of a generally accepted definition of "ring extension" one way or another. $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ and "integral extension" is a generally accepted term.

Comment: If you search on "extension of rings" you will see that it is in wide use, e.g. "suppose $\,R\subseteq S$ is an extension of rings..."